# Hadoop program (java) to read comma separated input file

Tags: java, csv, hadoop

I have an input file that looks like below

```
000001928162247ffaf63185cd8b2a244c78e7c6,2009324,abcat0101001,Sharp,"2011-09-05 12:25:37.42","2011-09-05 12:25:01.187"
0001be1731ee7d1c519bc7e87110c9eb880cb396,1649294,abcat0715001,"Gunnar eyewear","2011-09-23 17:13:36.175","2011-09-23 17:12:18.389"
0001bfa0c494c01f9f8c141c476c11bb4625a746,17240521,cat02015,refrigerator,"2011-10-19 23:43:51.71","2011-10-19 23:43:06.485"
0001fb09f03fea4d04e2267ed3194c806839d997,1271997,abcat0513004,Razer,"2011-09-07 09:20:07.11","2011-09-07 09:19:03.279"
0002965b083b6e508f7740c47c8f39e1072b4219,3562379,pcmcat209400050001,"I phone 4","2011-10-27 14:10:31.92","2011-10-27 14:09:33.327"
0002bb28a9ca07f5515b01996fd5d7ca84742e41,3230638,pcmcat177200050009,"hd antenna","2011-10-20 00:03:49.966","2011-10-20 00:02:01.458"
0002bd9c3d654698bb514194c4f4171ad6992266,9947181,pcmcat253300050012,printer,"2011-10-06 19:51:40.984","2011-10-06 19:47:13.803"
0002fee45e1c32eb94e82fc6c15c4db14e796248,3519969,pcmcat247400050000,vaio,"2011-10-19 23:31:51.015","2011-10-19 23:31:12.213"
00042033d355973baf9454b021a15c6b5b48f4a3,2677297,pcmcat212600050008,"desk top","2011-08-29 12:03:38.265","2011-08-29 12:03:12.348"
000433e0ef411c2cb8ee1727002d6ba15fe9426b,8959317,cat02015,"how i met your mother","2011-09-17 19:44:40.129","2011-09-17 19:43:37.564"
```

which contains the following information

```
user_id,product_id,category,query,click_time,query_time
```

I want to read this file in Hadoop and extract the user_id and the category (the 1st and 3rd fields). I have a basic Hadoop program as below that I used for wordcount. In this task, the items are separated by comma, and I have to store them in ArrayList.

Here is my starting program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;


import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.TokenCounterMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.IntSumReducer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;

public class popularcats extends Configured implements Tool {

  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job(getConf());
    job.setJarByClass(getClass());
    job.setMapperClass(TokenCounterMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new popularcats(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }

}
```

I suppose Hadoop must have some classes for reading in a CSV file. I found this class CSVLineRecordReader from this address
https://github.com/mvallebr/CSVInputFormat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CSVLineRecordReader.java

So how should i process this file and extract the desired fields?